# Spring Data MongoDB - updateMulti of field using value from another field

Tags: spring, mongodb

In my project, I need to duplicate values from one field into a new field within the same document.
Something like changing this:

```
{
"_id" : "Some ID",
"listOfObjects" : [ 
    {
        "item" : "One"
    }, 
    {
        "item" : "Two"
    }
]
}
```

to this:

```
{
"_id" : "Some ID",
"listOfObjects" : [ 
    {
        "item" : "One"
    }, 
    {
        "item" : "Two"
    }
],
"newList" : [ 
    {
        "item1" : "One"
    }, 
    {
        "item1" : "Two"
    }
]
}
```

note that newList is a copy of listOfObjects, and the field item is mapped to item1.
I managed do this inside the mongo shell like so:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').updateMany({
"listOfObjects": {
    "$exists": true
}
}
,
[
{
"$set": {
    "newList": {
        $map: {
            input: "$listOfObjects",
            in: {
                item1: "$$this.item"
            }
        }
        
    }
}
}]
```

**My question is**, how do I do that with Spring Data?
I want to use mongoTemplate.updateMulti(), which I assume is the equivalent of .updateMany on the shell. Am I right?
(Sorry for the indentations... It's my first question on StackOverflow).

TIA,
Lior.

Comment: This answer could be helpfull for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/74023246/5519726